# Unity enemy ai always firing bullets high over the player

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics, rigid-bodies

Got an issue where the enemy will fire at the player, but always seems to go high or to the side of the player even when the player is stationary and isn't moving. Am I doing something wrong in my code which creates this wild issue or is it just a random annoying bug?

Using the same script for the player albeit it under a different name works, which leads me to believe the issue lies within the fire point. Under the player's script I fire like so:

```
 // Get the place the player has clicked
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

            // Holds information regarding the mouseclick
            RaycastHit hitInfo;

            // Now work out if we fire or not
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hitInfo))
            {
                if(hitInfo.distance < maxRange)
                {
                    FireAtPoint(hitInfo.point);
```

Whereas in the enemy script it is just done through the player's position.

```
// Holds information regarding the mouseclick
            RaycastHit hitInfo;

            // Now work out if we fire or not
            if (Physics.Raycast(player.transform.position,transform.forward, out hitInfo))
            {
```

Is this underlying issue in the Physics.Raycast call then?

Rest of code for reference:

```
//More above this but doesn't influence the firing
if (Physics.Raycast(player.transform.position,transform.position, out hitInfo))
{
    if (hitInfo.distance < maxRange)
    {
       FireAtPoint(hitInfo.point);
    }
}


private void FireAtPoint(Vector3 point)
{

// Get the velocity to fire out at
var velocity = FiringVelocity(point, angle);

Rigidbody rg = Instantiate(bulletPrefab.gameObject, firePoint.position, firePoint.rotation).GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

EnemyBulletController newProjectile = rg.GetComponent<EnemyBulletController>();

newProjectile.speed = velocity;

}


private Vector3 FiringVelocity(Vector3 destination, float angle)
{
// Get the direction of the mouse click from the player, then get the height differential. 
Vector3 direction = destination - transform.position;
float height = direction.y;
height = 0;

// Get the distance in a float of the vector3
float distance = direction.magnitude;

// Turn the firing angle into radians for calculations, then work out any height differential
float AngleRadians = angle * Mathf.Deg2Rad;
direction.y = distance * Mathf.Tan(AngleRadians);
distance += height / Mathf.Tan(AngleRadians);

// Calculate the velocity magnitude
float velocity = Mathf.Sqrt(distance * Physics.gravity.magnitude / Mathf.Sin(2 * AngleRadians));

// Return the normalized vector to fire at.
return velocity * direction.normalized;
}
```

Picture for reference:

[image: Bullet Over the top]

Comment: @TobiasTheel Not much use when parabolically firing and not firing in a straight line though....

Comment: not sure about the correctness of your equations

Answer (score 2):

Your equation for computing the velocity looks doubtful. Let's re-derive it:

[image]

The equations of free-fall motion under constant gravity are:

[image]

After rearranging by substituting the first into the second, we find an expression for the firing velocity:

[image]

This is different to what you have, as you are missing the `h/d` term; said term also gives a constraint on the allowed values of `θ`:

[image]

(Basically means that if you fire *directly* at the target the bullet would never reach due to gravity)

There are many other problems with your code; just to list three:

- Why set `height` to zero?
- Why add a correction to `distance`? The correction has no physical interpretation.
- The fix suggested by @BasillePerrnoud

Amended code:

```
private Vector3 FiringVelocity(Vector3 destination, float angle)
{
   Vector3 direction = destination - transform.position;
   float height = direction.y;
   float distance = Mathf.Sqrt(direction.x * direction.x + direction.z * direction.z);  // *horizontal* distance

   float radians = angle * Mathf.Deg2Rad;
   float hOverd = height / distance;
   float tanAngle = Mathf.Tan(radians);

   if (tanAngle <= hOverd)
       // throw an exception or return an error code, because no solution exists for v

   float cosAngle = Mathf.Cos(radians);
   direction.Y = distance / cosAngle;

   float velocity = Mathf.Sqrt((distance * Physics.gravity.magnitude) / 
                   (2 * cosAngle * cosAngle * (tanAngle - hOverd)));
   return velocity * direction.normalized;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that exacerbates the issue making the height differential even worse.
https://imgur.com/a/5GGUk

Comment: As well the above works for the player when they use a ray to determine where to fire at, now it's where the player's transform should be.

Comment: @Robertgold well you did apply the fix from `BasilePerrenoud`'s answer right?

Comment: Yes I did that and that didn't work and still goes high.

Answer (score 1):

I think you use Raycast wrongly. According to the [doc](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html), the second argument is the direction, not the destination:

```
if (Physics.Raycast(player.transform.position,transform.position, out hitInfo))
```

Should be

```
if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, player.transform.position -
    transform.position, out hitInfo))
```

That would explain why it is not firing at the right moment and why the direction is not accurate (since `hitInfo` is wrong)

Comment: Still shooting high over the player

Comment: If I still do,                 Physics.Raycast(player.transform.position,transform.forward, out hitInfo)) Then it's still shooting high.

Comment: If the direction is transform.forward and it doesn't go forward, either you somehow rotated your scene and the forward vector is pointing up (Easy to check, it is the z axis, in blue in the editor). Or, ore likely, it is your height correction function that has a problem (like @meowgoesthedog suggested). You should try removing the height correction and check what happens. If you then see a correct behaviour (correct direction but too low), try fixing the correction function.